# How to insert new table value from different database along with its matching id in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have my two MYSQL database:

database 1 with table: `Employee` with the columns:

- `Employee_code` and
- `Employee _ID`

and database 2 with table: `Employee_log` with the columns:

- `Date`,
- `Time` and
- `Employee_ID`.

I have now, created a third database 3 with table: `Employee_Details`with the columns:

- `Employee_code`
- `Employee_ID`
- `Date` and
- `Time`.

I have also managed to insert date to the `Employee_Details` table using the following SQL Query:

```
 INSERT INTO database3.Employee_Details(Employee_ID, Employee_Code)
SELECT Employee_ID, Employee_Code FROM database 1.Employee;
```

but, now I want to include the `Date` and `Time` from database 2 table: `Employee_log` to the database 3 with the matching employee ID. I tried using the above code but the dates are getting inserted into the table after the `Employee_ID` in a new row with other column values NULL.

```
Example:
Employee_ID Employee_Code Date
1            1011
2            1012
Null         Null         09/05/2018
Null         Null         08/05/2018
```

So, how can I insert the date to its matching `Employee_id`, can someone please help me with this.
Thanks,

Comment: Any reason you aren't doing this all on one database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start over by first deleting all rows in `database3.Employee_Details`.

```
DELETE FROM database3.Employee_Details;
```

Next, do an `INSERT ... SELECT` like you did but join `database1.Employee` and `database2.Employee_log` this time.

```
INSERT INTO database3.Employee_Details
            (Employee_ID,
             Employee_Code,
             Date,
             Time)
            SELECT Employee.Employee_code,
                   Employee.Employee_ID,
                   Employee_log.Date,
                   Employee_log.Time
                   FROM database1.Employee
                        LEFT JOIN database2.Employee_log
                                  ON Employee_log.Employee_ID = Employee.Employee_ID;
```

In general a join combines the rows of two tables. Each row of the right table is appended to the row of the left table if the condition in the `ON` clause is true for that pair of rows.

There are some different flavors of joins. Here we use a `LEFT JOIN`. In a `LEFT JOIN` the rows of the left table (the table left of the `JOIN` keyword) are included in the result, even if there were no matching rows from the right table. Instead of the column values from the right table, the respective columns in the result are all null, as there are no values from matching rows.

In contrast a `INNER JOIN` has only those rows of the left table included where a matching row from the right table exists.

To include all employees, even if no log data was available for them, we had to choose a `LEFT JOIN` here.

If you don't want to start over, you can update `database3.Employee_Details` with the missing values.

```
UPDATE database3.Employee_Details
       LEFT JOIN database1.Employee_log
                 ON Employee_log.Employee_ID = Employee_Details.Employee_ID
       SET Employee_Details.Date = Employee_log.Date,
           Employee_Details.Time = Employee_log.Time;
```

Again we use a `LEFT JOIN` and set the fields in the `SET` clause with the respective values from the result of the join.

Afterwards delete the unnecessary rows with empty `Employee_ID`.

```
DELETE FROM database3.Employee_Details
       WHERE Employee_Details.Employee_ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the insert as:

```
INSERT INTO database3.Employee_Details(Employee_ID, Employee_Code)
    SELECT e.Employee_ID, e.Employee_Code, el.date
    FROM database 1.Employee e LEFT JOIN
         Employee_log el
         ON e.Employee_ID = el.Employee_ID;
```

You might find it simpler to just create the table as:

```
CREATE TABLE database3.Employee_Details as 
    SELECT e.Employee_ID, e.Employee_Code, el.date
    FROM database 1.Employee e LEFT JOIN
         Employee_log el
         ON e.Employee_ID = el.Employee_ID;
```